# Calling Script Function With Range Of Parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How to call `myFunction(myParameter)` from range?

I have column with parameters and want to calculate another.

```
Parameter Column   Result Column

Cell 1             res=myFunction(Cell 1)
....               ....
Cell n             res=myFunction(Cell n)
```

`INDIRECT(range)` with `ARRAYFORMULA` not working:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(myFunction(INDIRECT(Range))
```

This returns only one result with the first parameter from the range.

Answer (score 0):

*Presuming `muFunction` is a custom function you wrote in Google App Script.*

Your custom function will not iterate inside `ARRAYFORMULA`. You need to modify it to be able to work with a range passed as input and to return a range to fill the cells downwards.

You can find the details and an example in the official docs:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets - Optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)

After that you will be able to call it like so:

```
=myFunction(A:A)
```